# My java code to get first string alphabetically using recursion gives incorrect output. Do I need to add a helper method?

Tags: java, recursion

I am having trouble getting `s1` and `s2` to compare properly. If I add multiple strings to my `ArrayList<String>`,  it seems to stop after running once. So I am missing a recursive method to help my `findMinimum` method I think.

I need to provide code to create a `Tester` class but I am just trying to create a working program at this point. Any help is appreciated. I do need to use recursion for this assignment otherwise I would use a different route.

```
    public class BigComp {
    // public static String s1;
    // public static String s2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // String s1 = "badd"; //, "job", "any";
    // String s2 = "hat";//,"zFat","got";
    ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringArray.add("acc");
    stringArray.add("Dbc");
    stringArray.add("bac");
    // compareTo(s1,s2);
    // findMinimum(stringArray);
    System.out.println(findMinimum(stringArray));
  }

      public static int compareTo(String s1, String s2) {

    if(s1.charAt(0) < s2.charAt(0)) {
      return -1; // String s1 is alphabetically before s2
    }
    if(s1.charAt(0) > s2.charAt(0)) {
      return 1; // String s1 is alphabetically after s2
    }
    if(s1.charAt(0) == s2.charAt(0)) {
      if(s1.length()== 1 && s2.length() ==1) {
          return 0; // both strings being compared are identical
      }
      if(s1.length() == 1 && s2.length() > 1) {
          return -1; // s1 is before s2
      }
      if(s1.length() > 1 && s2.length()== 1) {
          return 1; // s2 is before s1
      }
    }
    return compareTo(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1));

  } // end of compareTo method

    public static String findMinimum(ArrayList<String> stringArray) {

    String s1 = stringArray.get(0);
    int max = stringArray.size()-1;
    String s2 = stringArray.get(max);
    int temp = compareTo(s1, s2);

    // if(stringArray.size() == 1) {
    //     return stringArray.get(0);
    // }

    if(temp == 0) {
      stringArray.remove(max);
      return findMinimum(stringArray);
    }
    else if(temp == 1) {
      stringArray.remove(s1);
      return findMinimum(stringArray);
    }
    else {
      stringArray.remove(s2);
      return findMinimum(stringArray);
    }

  } // end findMinimum method

} // end of BigComp class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will get an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because method `findMinimum` has no case for the stop of recursion. You can add this line at the begin of the method `findMinimum`:

```java
if (stringArray.size() == 1) return stringArray.get(0);
```

`.charAt` returns char type, that means they will be compared by ASCII code. Maybe you need to use `compareToIgnoreCase`:

```java
public static int compareTo(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
}
```

Comment: I had that in my code commented out because I was trying to find out where my error was occurring.  It's still returning "Dbc" but I need the minimum string alphabetically.

Comment: still getting INdexOutOfBounds for the compareTo method